# WordPress different menu layout file

Tags: wordpress, menu

You can have an index file that diverts the users to template a/b/c depending on if they want a sidebar on the left/right/none. Is it possible to do the same with a Nav Bar, have a Nav Bar file that diverts the user to navbar template file a/b/c depending on some option they have selected?

Comment: Yes you can make different menu structure using manu walker

Comment: Its not the structure I want to change, it's the layout. So in one case I might want the menu right at the top of the page, and in another, beneath the logo etc